# Java casting understanding

Tags: java, types, casting

```
public class Maryland extends State { Maryland() { /* null constructor */ }
    public void printMe() { System.out.println("Read it."); }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Region mid = new State();
        State md = new Maryland();
        Object obj = new Place();
        Place usa = new Region();
        md.printMe();
        mid.printMe();
        ((Place) obj).printMe();
        obj = md;
        ((Maryland) obj).printMe();
        obj = usa;
        ((Place) obj).printMe();
        usa = md;
        ((Place) usa).printMe();
    }
}
class State extends Region {
    State() { /* null constructor */ }
    public void printMe() { System.out.println("Ship it."); }
}
class Region extends Place {
    Region() { /* null constructor */ }
    public void printMe() { System.out.println("Box it."); }
}
class Place extends Object {
    Place() { /* null constructor */ }
    public void printMe() { System.out.println("Buy it."); }
}
```

Hi There.

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of the above main method which prints the following output when run.

Read it.
 Ship it.
 Buy it.
 Read it.
 Box it.
 Read it.

I'm particularly struggling to understand the output of the last two printMe methods in the main function.

My understanding is that the first two print me operations will use there super classes printMe method as the objects have not been explicitly downcast to the sub class and thus are considered to be State and Region objects respectively by the Java compiler.

I also believe I understand the next two outputs in which the classes are downcast and thus the subclass printMe functions will override the superclass functions.

However I am struggling to understand what is occurring in the last two printMe methods. I can see that the variable obj is initially declared as an Object and then downcast as a Place is assigned a reference to the usa object(of type Place). So why is the output then of type region in this instance? I feel I am missing fundamental here in my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, instance method calls follow inheritance. No matter what the reference type is, it will call the method of the type of the actual object.

The type of the reference only determine which methods the compiler knows you can call. e.g.

```
String hi = "Hello";
Object A = hi;
String hiToString = A.toString(); // calls String.toString();
int l = A.length(); // won't compile even though the String in A has a length() method.
```

Note: for static methods, the instance is ignored and it is the compile time type which determines which method is called.

Comment: In OOP or in Java ? Because I though C++ was doing the opposite, calling the method of the reference (or pointer)

Comment: @ortis in C++ `virtual` methods do the same thing. C++ avoids making all methods virtual for performance reasons, which Java solves by using dynamic compilation. +1, I have clarified the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Do the casts then have any significance in this example or could they be left out without changing the output of the code without a compiler error?

Comment: @AdamBurke In this example, they make no difference. Whether you have the cast or not, you can call those methods.  A cast could either a) restrict access to a method, or b) expose a method, in these case a cast makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, non-static methods are called with late-binding, which means we cannot make sure which function it will call until run-time.

> My understanding is that the first two print me operations will use there super classes printMe method as the objects have not been explicitly downcast to the sub class and thus are considered to be State and Region objects respectively by the Java compiler.

- Explicitly downcast does nothing in this code. Downcast is actually performed.
- Object `md` is still a reference to `State` and Object `mid` is a reference of `Region`. Compiler will never know which `printMe()` will be called. It only checks that `State` and `Region` classes have the function `printMe()` or not.
- At run-time, when the `md.printMe()` is called, JVM will check the Runtime type information (RTTI) of `md`, and know it is a Object of `State` class. Therefore, the `printMe()` function in the `State` class is called, no matter what `md` is declared. (Of course, you need to override the `printMe()` in the `State` class. If you don't, `State` class will inherit the `printMe()` function from its superclass `Place`, and the `printMe()` function in `Place` class will be called. You can check this by removing the `printMe()` function in your `State` class.)

According to these rules, the output is reasonable.

The type cast in `((Place) obj).printMe()` is needed just because in `Object` class, there's no `printMe()` function in it. Still, the compiler can't make sure which function `((Place) obj).printMe()` will called, it is decided at run-time. For example, if you change your `((Maryland) obj).printMe();` to `((Place) obj).printMe();`, the output is still the same.

For static methods, these rules will not fit. You can read more information about them with the keywords "Overloading, Overriding and Hiding". These terminologies will help you to understand the inheritance system in Java.